# Django - arbitrary text inputs widget

Tags: python, django

Im looking for way, to implement an input in admin interface which will allow to spawn arbitrary text-fields (or better to say defined not-dynamic set of UI elements), write something there, and then it must be stored in DB in single cell (as JSON probably).

Do I need to reinvent the wheel to do this in Django, or solutions are already exists?

Comment: One way: Create the input using Javascript, then implement a custom `save()` method to store the data.

Comment: You will have to invent this one yourself. There are frontend frameworks that do this for you (pure JS to 0-N forms to JSON).